# StackOverflowError while trying to Reverse an Array using Recursion

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, stack-overflow

I've written a recursive method for reversing an array.

It produces a `StackOverflowError`, and I just can't figure out why. I'm sure it's something simple, but I've been stuck here for 2 hours trying to fix it.

*My code:*

```
public static void reverseArray(char[] input, int i, int j) {
    char temp;
    if (i >= j) return;
    
    else if (i < j) {
        temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[j];
        input[j] = temp;
        reverseArray(input, i++, j--);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should change the *post-increment/post-decrement* to *pre-increment/pre-decrement* in the recursive call:

```
reverseArray(input, ++i, --j);
```

`i++` would change only the value of `i` that exists in the scope of the current method call, but the argument received by the recursive call would be the **initial value** of `i` (same holds true for `j`).

So basically you're passing the same indices and for that reason getting a `StackOverflowError`.

Also **note** that there's no need to wrap the *recursive case* with `else if`.

```
public static void reverseArray(char[] input, int i, int j) {
    
    if (i >= j) return;
    
    char temp = input[i];
    input[i] = input[j];
    input[j] = temp;
    
    reverseArray(input, ++i, --j);
}
```

Alternatively, as *@Slaw* has suggested in the comments, to avoid confusion you can explicitly *add/subtract* one while making a recursive call:

```
reverseArray(input, i + 1, j - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error! Now I just have to figure out why it reverses the array multiple times until it repeats the same word as the original input

Comment: @SushiSlicer Your code would fine with the fix I've mentioned (`++i` and `--j`). See the [online demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/vUx). I've added a print statement and removed some redundancy.

Comment: @SushiSlicer Personally, I would use `i + 1` and `j - 1`, just to make it completely clear.

Comment: @Slaw Agree, it's good to keep the code simple, included this idea into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing (x++, y--) to (++x, --y)